# ООП на php (sql запросы в моделе Codeigniter)

Tags: ооп, mvc, php, codeigniter, mysql

Добрый день! Изучаю ООП на php модель MVS фреймворк codeigniter.

у меня есть модель

```
public function numb_vagon($number_vagona)
    {
        $this->db->order_by('disla_date');
        $this->db->where('number_vagona', $number_vagona);

        $res = $this->db->get($this->_table);
        if ($res)
        {
            return $res->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

есть контроллер

```
public function HistoryWagonResult()
    {
        $query = $this->Unload_model->numb_vagon($number_vagona);
        $data['query'] = $query;
        $this->load->view('pages_view/history_vagon_result_view', $data);
    }
```

и так же вьюшка

```
<? foreach ($query as $row): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?=$row->naznachenie ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->operation ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->date ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->time ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->op ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->dpr ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->index_poezd ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->gruz ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->ves ?></td>
                                        <td><?=$row->grpol ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                      <? endforeach; ?>
```

суть работы я ввожу в строку поиска номер вагона, и мне должен вывестись результат в таблице, естственно выдаются ошибки по $number_vagona. на чистом php у меня получается сделать. но сейчас мне требуется реализовать на codeigniter 
        вообще как правильно передается переменная,
        просто я доконца не понимаю, вообще как правильно тут описать $number_vagona и где

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$number_vagona = $this->input->post('nomer_vagona');
```

не описала в контролера,
теперь все работет